# Which url is the correct to show 404 to robots?

Tags: url, http-status-code-404

Which url is the correct to show 404 to robots?

http://domainname.com/404pagenotfound.php

Page contains 404 content

(or)

http://domainname.com/lldfgjldfjg.php

Page contains 404 content

I.e Do I want to redirect the mismatched url to 404pagenotfound.php

OR

Do I want to show page not found in the same mismatched url.

Comment: Does it make any difference? They're going to discard the result anyway. (Assuming we're talking about search engine crawlers here.)

Answer (score 0):

user has to have a possibility how to edit the URL (eg. when they only mistype).

So, URL http://domainname.com/lldfgjldfjg.php with 404 status code for search engines and 404 text message for user is the ideal way.